# conditional filtering dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Data:

```
DF<-tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,        ~DATE,   ~SIDE,
   1L, "2010-10-10",  "LEFT",
   2L, "2005-05-05", "RIGHT",
   2L, "2006-06-06", "RIGHT",
   3L, "2007-07-07",  "LEFT",
   3L, "2008-08-08", "RIGHT",
   3L, "2009-09-09",  "LEFT",
   4L, "2010-10-10",  "LEFT",
   4L, "2011-11-11",      NA,
   5L,           NA,  "LEFT"
  )
```

Desired output:

```
     ID INDX_DATE  SIDE  SEC_DATE  
    
1     1 2010-10-10 LEFT  NA        
2     2 2005-05-05 RIGHT 2006-06-06
3     3 2007-07-07 LEFT  2009-09-09
4     4 2010-10-10 LEFT  NA
```

Logic:

Everything is grouped by `ID`.
`INDX_DATE` is the first `DATE` in that `ID`. `SEC_DATE`is the nextcoming `DATE` where `SIDE`is the same as on the `INDX_DATE`.

Anyone eager to help? :)
/H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DF %>%
  summarise(INDX_DATE = first(DATE), 
            SEC_DATE = DATE[SIDE == first(SIDE)][2],
            SIDE = SIDE[1], .by = ID)

# A tibble: 5 × 4
     ID INDX_DATE  SEC_DATE   SIDE 
  <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1     1 2010-10-10 NA         LEFT 
2     2 2005-05-05 2006-06-06 RIGHT
3     3 2007-07-07 2009-09-09 LEFT 
4     4 2010-10-10 NA         LEFT
```

You can then drop ID's whose `INDX_DATE` is `NA` ie `..%>%filter(!is.na(INDX_DATE))`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately i get "cant supply .by when  data is grouped dataframe", when applying to my original data.

Comment: @hklovs transform that into `DF%>%group_by(ID) %>%summarise(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job

```
library(tidyverse)
```

If by the next coming DATE you mean last date as in group 3 `2009-09-09` is last date not next from the first.

```
DF %>%
  filter(!is.na(DATE)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(DATE = ifelse(is.na(SIDE), NA, DATE)) %>%
  summarise(INDEX_DATE = first(DATE),
            SIDE = first(SIDE),
            SEC_DATE = ifelse( n() ==1, NA, last(DATE)))


     ID INDEX_DATE SIDE  SEC_DATE  
  <int> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     
1     1 2010-10-10 LEFT  NA        
2     2 2005-05-05 RIGHT 2006-06-06
3     3 2007-07-07 LEFT  2009-09-09
4     4 2010-10-10 LEFT  NA
```

If by the next coming DATE you mean actually the second

````
DF %>%
  filter(!is.na(DATE)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(DATE = ifelse(is.na(SIDE), NA, DATE)) %>%
  summarise(INDEX_DATE = first(DATE),
            SIDE = first(SIDE),
           SEC_DATE = DATE[2])

     ID INDEX_DATE SIDE  SEC_DATE  
  <int> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     
1     1 2010-10-10 LEFT  NA        
2     2 2005-05-05 RIGHT 2006-06-06
3     3 2007-07-07 LEFT  2008-08-08
4     4 2010-10-10 LEFT  NA  


```
````

Comment: There are syntax errors in this code and the output does not match what the OP requested.

Comment: just updated the code corrected the spelling issues, provide two solutions depending on what you mean by the next DATE, in ID 3 "2009-09-09" is actually the third date, so that is not the next date.

Comment: @Macosso ID `2009-09-09` is the second date corresponding to side `LEFT`. So this code is INcorrect

Comment: Thanks Macosso. Unfortunately the code is not following the logic i asked for. See comment from Onyambu.

Comment: Unless you provide deails on what is not being achieved by the code, wont be easy to help. The 3 answers provided are replicating your expected results, Wont be possible to come up with solution not listed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DF %>% 
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>%         # make DATE to be date class
  filter(DATE == min(DATE), .by = ID) %>%  # filter over minimun date (first date) grouping by ID
  left_join(                               # merge the following DF
    DF %>% 
      filter(DATE != min(DATE), .by = ID) %>%  # remove first dates
      rename(DATE_SEC=DATE),               # rename DATE in the second DF 
    by = c("ID", "SIDE")                   # set key for merging
    )                                      # get your desired result
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     ID DATE       SIDE  DATE_SEC  
  <int> <date>     <chr> <date>    
1     1 2010-10-10 LEFT  NA        
2     2 2005-05-05 RIGHT 2006-06-06
3     3 2007-07-07 LEFT  2009-09-09
4     4 2010-10-10 LEFT  NA
```